# Firebase Messaging : cannot read property of undefined addEventListener

Tags: node.js, firebase, vue.js, firebase-cloud-messaging, addeventlistener

I created a Firebase App using NodeJS/VueJS and trying to setup Cloud Messaging.

I created a firebase-messaging-sw.js file, and added messaging on my main.js.

On my app I included firebase and on my mounted I did this ([as stated on the doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/client#web-version-8_1)) :

```
    const messaging = firebase.messaging();

    messaging.getToken({ vapidKey: "<KEY>" })
            .then((currentToken) => {
                if (currentToken) {
                    console.log('client token', currentToken)
                } else {
                    console.log('No registration token available. Request permission to generate one.');
                }
            }).catch((err) => {
                console.log('An error occurred while retrieving token. ', err);
    });
```

Then I am going to my webapp and I have the following error :
"Uncaught TypeError : cannot read property of undefined (reading 'addEventListener')"

This error kinda lost me since I don't know where does it come from.

When looking on the error I saw that :

[image: error screenshot]

Looking into the source register.ts it redirects me to this :

```
navigator.serviceWorker.addEventListener('message', e =>
messageEventListener(messaging as MessagingService, e));
```

But I don't understand the problem, I tried to describe as much as possible all the steps that leaded to the error. Even when I comment the code of my mounted I still have the error

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Did you find a solution to that problem ? If so how did you fix it ?

Comment: No I did not sadly. I gave up, used a simple mailer system instead.

Comment: This error is still present. It happens right after calling `const messaging = getMessaging(app);`. I also received another error after this one: `FirebaseError: Messaging: This browser doesn't support the API's required to use the Firebase SDK. (messaging/unsupported-browser).`, while calling `isSupported()` from `firebase/messaging` returns true. I assume it's due `addEventListener` error.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out. I was using FCM inside service worker, which apparently I shouldn't be doing. FCM tries to call `addEventListener` on `navigator.serviceWorker`, but `navigator.serviceWorker` isn't defined in service worker and that leads us to this error.

You should implement FCM in separate script. Let's call it `initFCM.js`:

```js
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app"
import { getMessaging, getToken } from "firebase/messaging";

const firebaseConfig = {
  // your Firebase config
  // TODO: Replace the following with your app's Firebase project configuration
  // See: https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/learn-more#config-object
}

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

// Initialize Firebase Cloud Messaging and get a reference to the service
const messaging = getMessaging(app);

getToken(messaging, { vapidKey: "<KEY>" })
        .then((currentToken) => {
            if (currentToken) {
                console.log('client token', currentToken)
            } else {
                console.log('No registration token available. Request permission to generate one.');
            }
        }).catch((err) => {
            console.log('An error occurred while retrieving token. ', err);
});
```

Now you just include this script in html:

```
<script type="module" src="initFCM.js"></script>
```

And that's it. Please note that I implemented this using "Web version 9" instead of "Web version 8".

Answer (score 0):

The fix is to import the right part in the service worker.
instead of

import { getMessaging } from "firebase/messaging/";

use

import { getMessaging } from "firebase/messaging/sw";

keep your logic and it will work.